# How can I echo subdirectory + all the files inside?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Sorry, there is my updated question.

I want to echo all the subfolders and all the files with a specific extension that are inside those subfolders. I would like to echo them like this :

```
Subfolder 1 :
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Subfolder1\File1.mjb"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Subfolder1\File2.mjb"
Subfolder 2 :
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Subfolder2\File1.mjb"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Subfolder2\File2.mjb"
Subfolder 3 :
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Subfolder3\File1.mjb"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Subfolder3\File2.mjb"
```

At the moment, I only manage to echo all the files. So there is two things to see :

1. How can I echo both of this things.
2. How can I echo specific file only.

There is my actual code :

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set ext=".mjb"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%_FolderName%"^| findstr /vile "!ext!"') do echo "%%F"
```

And this is my actual result (I'm trying this in a test_env) :

```
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein1\Fichier1.qds"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein1\Fichier2.txt"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein1\Fichier4.iso"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein1\Fichier5.iso"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein1\Fichier6.mjb"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein1\Plein1\Fichier1.iso"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein1\Plein1\Fichier2.mjb"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein1\Plein1\Fichier3.mjb"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein1\Plein1\Fichier4.wmf"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein2\Fichier1.txt"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein2\Fichier4.pdf"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein2\Fichier5.iso"
"C:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test\Plein2\Fichier6.mjb"
```

Comment: Your question requires more information. We need to know what your current output looks like, and what your intended output is. Without this we cannot make a reasonable attempt at determining a solution for you. Please use the [edit] facility, and place those outputs in two distinct code boxes for us. It would also assist us if you were to include the tree, (please open a Command Prompt window, type `tree.com /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key to see its usage information).

Comment: `for /D /R "%UserProfile%\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test" %%J in (*) do echo(%%~J& for %%I in ("%%~J\*.mjb") do echo(%%~I`?

Comment: It's working for the files with a specific extension but it shows me all subfolders, I just wanted the subfolder's name of those that had the concerned files. I didn't mentionned that explicitly but you can see it in my first exemple.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "_FolderName=u:\Users\546802\Desktop\outil_5s\env_test"
set "ext=mjb"
SET "currentdir="
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%_FolderName%\*.%ext%"') do (
 IF "!currentdir!" neq "%%~dpb" ( 
  SET "currentdir=%%~dpb"
  FOR %%c IN ("%%~dpb.") DO ECHO %%~nxc :
  SET "files_dir=%%~dpb"
  SET "files_dir=!files_dir:%_FolderName%\=!"
  ECHO !files_dir:~0,-1! :
 )
 echo "%%b"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Somewhat unclear what you want to do.

Your code performs a `findstr` with the `/v` option, so it will select all lines that **do not** match the mask provided, but the mask provided is resolved to `"".mjb""` because you are assigning the quotes within the `set` statement, then re-quoting it.

It's not clear what header you are asking for where the filename is `...5s\env_test\Plein1\Fichier2.mjb` - which may have the same name as `...5s\env_test\Plein1\Plein1\Fichier2.mjb`. Is it the direct parent name (`plein1` for both instances) or should there be a distinction?

The `dir` statement above selects all of the `.mjb` files which appears to be your goal.

`currentdir` keeps trac of the last parent directory found. If it changes, I've shown two possibilities. The first potential header shown is simply the parent directory name.

The second is calculated by removing the starting directory name from the absolute pathname of the file.

Note that I changed metavariables because `F` can be confused with `~f` (the full-filename modifier operator) and that my testing was performed on drive `u:` (my RAMdrive)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Magoo. Here is the exact thing of what I wanted exactly.

```
for /F "Tokens=1 Delims=" %%I in ('cscript //nologo explo_fichier.vbs') do set _FolderName=%%I
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "ext=mjb"
set "currentdir="
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%_FolderName%\*.%ext%"') do (
 if "!currentdir!" neq "%%~dpb" ( 
  set "currentdir=%%~dpb"
  for %%c IN ("%%~dpb.") do echo %%~nxc :
 )
 echo "%%b"
)
```

I have a script that opens me the file explorer so I can choose which folder I want to test :

> explo_fichier.vbs

```
Const MY_COMPUTER = &H11&
Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0
Const OPTIONS = 0

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(MY_COMPUTER)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
strPath = objFolderItem.Path

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder _
    (WINDOW_HANDLE, "Select a folder:", OPTIONS, strPath)
     
If objFolder Is Nothing Then
    Wscript.Quit
End If

Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
objPath = objFolderItem.Path

Wscript.Echo objPath
```

The goal of that is to get those informations so I can zip recursively all this files in a folder with the name of the parent folder. So my first step was getting those informations and now I will use a VBS script that zips everything as I want.